# C++ string array & for loop doesnt work as i expected

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char num[10];
   int a;
   cout << "Odd or Even"<< endl;
   for(;;)
   {
      cout << "Enter Number:" ;
      cin >> num;
      cout << endl;
      for(a=9;a>=0;a--)
      {
         if(num[a]!='\0 && num[a]!=' ')
            break;
      }
      if(num[a]==1 || num[a]==3 || num[a]==5 || num[a]==7 || num[a]==9)
         cout << "Odd" << endl;
      else
         cout << "Even" << endl;
   }
}
```

I am a rookie of C++,and I wrote a program to discriminate if a number is even or odd,
but no matter what number I enter, it only outputs "Even".
So I added these to find out when did the loop breaks:

```
cout << a << endl;
cout << "\"" << num[a] << "\"" << endl;
```

Result：

```
Enter Number:11
9
" "
Even
```

the for loop beraks when `num[9]=' '`? Which will lead to else and always output "Even".

Comment: `if(num[a]==1` ... Try `if(num[a]=='1'`.

Comment: Your approach is wrong, try to take an int array instead of a char array for numbers.

Comment: an int is four bytes and a char is only one byte,so is a number,so if i take int num[80] instead of char num[80],three-fourths of the 80*4=320 bytes will be filled with ' ' which is a waste of memory.Also if i take int ,the compiler build message will list hundreds of "argument......"which i dont want to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused about the character `'1'` and the number `1`. They are different.

Instead of

```
  if(num[a]==1 || num[a]==3 || num[a]==5 || num[a]==7 || num[a]==9)
```

you need

```
  if(num[a]=='1' || num[a]=='3' || num[a]=='5' || num[a]=='7' || num[a]=='9')
```

**Update**

There is one more problems that is probably tripping you up.

1. `num` is not initialized. Zero-initialize it. Remember `0` is not the same as the character `'0'`.

   ```
   char num[10] = {0};
   ```
2. Move the initialization of `num` inside the `for` loop. That will eliminate the problem of data from a previous execution of the loop from affecting the current execution of the loop.

Here's a version that works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Odd or Even"<< endl;
   for(;;)
   {
      char num[10] = {0};
      int a;
      cout << "Enter Number:" ;
      cin >> num;
      cout << endl;
      for(a=9;a>=0;a--)
      {
         if(num[a]!='\0' && num[a]!=' ')
            break;
      }
      cout << num[a] << endl;
      if(num[a]=='1' || num[a]=='3' || num[a]=='5' || num[a]=='7' || num[a]=='9')
         cout << "Odd" << endl;
      else
         cout << "Even" << endl;
   }
}
```

**PS**

You can replace the line

```
         if(num[a]!='\0' && num[a]!=' ')
```

by

```
         if(isdigit(num[a]))
```

That makes more sense to me.

Comment: thanks for your correction , but the program still goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this with c++ there are much easier ways! Consider the following:

```
while (!done) {
    string inputline;
    getline(cin, inputline); //Now we have a string with the users input!

    stringstream ss; // stringstreams help us parse data in strings!
    int num; // We have a number we want to put it into.
    ss >> num; // We can use the string stream to parse this number. 
               // You can even add error checking!

    // Now to check for odd even, what do we know about even numbers? divisable by 2!
    if (num % 2 == 0) // No remainder from /2
       cout << Even << '\n'
    else
       cout << Odd << '\n'
}
```

see how you go with that!

*Warning* Untested code

Comment: i know there`s a lot of ways faster ,but i still want to know the errors I made.

Comment: Thats fine there are plenty of answers that show you where your problem was. I am just trying to show a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake (typo) here in this line..

`if(num[a]!='\0 && num[a]!=' ')`

it should be

`if(num[a]!='\0' && num[a]!=' ')`

Comment: thanks but that`s the typo i made in stackflow not on the editor